# How to reuse type definition in childContextTypes in react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using `Typescript` to develop `React`, I want to use `childContextTypes` in a `Component`:

```
import * as React from "react";

interface Props {
  foo: string;
  bar: string;
}

export class Parent extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
    constructor(props:Props, context:any) {
      super(props, context);
    }

    static childContextTypes =  {
      foo: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        bar: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    }

    getChildContext() {
        return this.props;
    }

    render() {
        return <Child />
    }
}

class Child extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
    context: any;

    static contextTypes = {
      foo: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        bar: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
    }

    render() {
      return <div>Hello, {this.context.foo}, {this.context.bar}</div>;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I just want to reuse all my `Props`, but in `childContextTypes` I have to specify all `childContextTypes` and I can not reuse `Props` interface.

**Can I reuse `Props`?** Why I need this? For now, I have only two props, but I may have much more props in some condition, I do not want to rewrite it!

Comment: MappedTypes new typescript feature might help with the rewrite same type definition: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#mapped-types

Comment: @OzBob , the "props" in this example, is a typescript interface, while static childContextProps, is at runtime, once tsc converts typescript files into javascript, the interface is totally gone, it is only used by your IDE, and thats it. while the types you set at childContextProps, seem to be attached even at runtime(independently of tsc) too. So, no, you can't reuse the "props" since you can't combine compile-time values, with run-time values in this particular case.